# auth() method null on Exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I was playing around with Laravel 5.4.23 and i came across this scenario when i hit a 404 page the `auth()`, `auth()->check()`, `auth()->user()`, and those are not initialized thus returning null in views, or anywhere near that.

i even went to AppServiceProvider.php class to do some tests,

```
dd(auth()->check());
```

returns Null in the `boot` method, even if i'm logged in, which makes 0 sense to me.

that means, whenever a users hits a 404 page, navbars and so on will not render the user data like for instance, traditionally we have the user profile button on top right side in navbar like here on stackoverflow, in that case in Laravel, this is not possible with what i'm seeing.

Am i on the right track or am i missing something ?

it appears to me that Laravel attempts to log the user in after completing the requests i tests.

hope i find the answer here.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

including a manual login attempt in the `boot` method in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider seemed to fix the null issue in the aut() commands, but i believe this will attempt to log the user in twice per page request, since obviously Laravel is getting the logged in user after the boot, exceptions requests and dunno what else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the session gets initialised by the `web` middleware group. When a route is not found the middleware never gets initialised. Therefore the application fails to find the authenticated user from the session.

There's a workaround for this though. Moving the session and cookie middleware from the `web` middleware group to the global middleware seems to fix this. But the downside is that every single route in your application with have sessions and cookies enabled by default. This can be problematic if you have api routes.

**MOVE** (don't copy) these routes from `web` middleware group (`$middlewareGroups`) to the global middleware list (`$middleware`).

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

You can skip the `EncryptCookies` middleware if you don't want to detect users using their remember_token in your error pages.

Comment: this still doesn't solve the issue that in AppServiceProvider, Auth::check() still returns false, it works in the Handlers but not in appserviceprovider, i'm trying to look into laravel source code to see if there's a possible way to load Auth before the rest

Comment: Why would you want to the auth user in the service provider?

Comment: i don't really need it, i just want to mess with laravel source code haha, so i'm trying to figure out how things work, so far your solution worked, i'm still checking in their source code, 1 week laravel user here :)

Comment: for example yesterday i created a new kind of relation which is capable of dealing with [Users, Freinds] tables, sender_id, recipient_id, etc etc, which belongsToMany isn't capable of understanding, today is the auth error which popped :)

Comment: Alright cool. Your case of access auth info in error pages is more than a common scenario. But accessing them in d service provider isn't. Service providers are what run first for the application to load, after which other codes get executed. So i see no point in digging deep into it. Anyway this question regarding the auth access in error pages is solved.

Comment: i just noticed that when i put these into the global middleware list i get a new issue, it is creating a new session everytime i refresh the page, the issue appeared after moving the session to db, it was however logging me out every once in a while even with increased session lifetime

nowi moved the middlewares to their normal web group and i'm no longer getting kicked out everytime i refresh the page, 
however, we're back to the previous issue (no auth in 404s)

Comment: @Emad i just checked again and it works perfectly without session getting cleared like you said. This was the same the first time i checked. I must be related to database sessions. The file sessions which i tested initially works fine.

Comment: i'm installing a fresh laravel 5.4.23 using composer in PhpStormg and will run it trough php artisan serve and test with blank fresh code to see if it's the middleware thing or something wrong with my code, however the middleware says startsession, as a result what i'm getting is a new session file/ db rows as well when i tested database sessions, on every refresh, ill get back to you shortly, thanks.

Comment: @Emad PHP `session_start();`, ring a bell? It's just the middleware naming, it starts the session thus enabling the usage of sessions. Doesn't mean it resets and starts the session on every request. Moving the middleware from the `web` group to global shouldn't create any differences in the way sessions work.

Comment: yea but it's not just session_start() in that middleware, any i just tested on a fresh copy and yea i'm not getting any new session on every refresh like on that other copy. tested as file and db driver, both are fine, there must be something i've done :) thanks, got any suggestion where to look ?

Comment: found it, issue was in Kernel, i COPIED the middlewares to globals, i should have moved them to globals, my bad and thanks again.