# Laravel auth() returns false on 404's

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I had an issue with Laravel when it throws a 404 exception, or any kind of exception, the auth() helper returns null in these pages, 404, 400... any exception.

As someone suggested, I moved 2 middlewares to the globalgroup

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
 \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

however, it caused another issue, it was logging me out everytime i refresh the page, when I moved these middlewares back logged in users stay logged in.

So now, I still need a way to use auth(), in 404 pages, it makes no sense that the navbar displays Please Login on 404 pages when the use is already logged in, that's really bad Laravel.

Actually the solution above suggested by many, cause lots of issues in the code, and detecting the authenticated user, I just did some tests, it was creating a new session upon every refresh.

Comment: are 404 pages throwing that? are those 404 pages custom pages?

Comment: @jycr753 404 pages are okay, i tried with editing handler and with custom /errors/404.blade.php files, 404 is not the issue, the issue is that when i visit a 404 page, inside the blade, i cannot seem to detect whether the user is logged in, auth()->check(), auth()->user() return false/null

Comment: @Emad i just checked again and it works perfectly without session getting cleared like you said. This was the same the first time i checked. I must be related to database sessions. The file sessions which i tested initially works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is solved at my previous related question [auth() method null on Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334983/auth-method-null-on-exceptions)

These middlewares should be *moved* and not copied to the global array. I had multiple instances, on web group and global group, which was causing the issue.

So copying the middlwares in `App/Http/Kernel.php` from the 'web' group to the 'middlewares' group will recreate the session on every refresh. I hope, someone will find this useful.